# The concept of Memory Leaks

Tags: memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I read this in a Java Text book(SL-275)

> Programs that do not de-allocate  memory can crash eventually when there is no memory left on the system to allocate. These programs are said to have *memory leaks*.

Why will there be *no memory left*? The systems usually have Hundreds Gigabytes of memory and the variable take 2-8 Bytes of data. Lets say we have 1000 undestroyed variables, thats just 8KB.
So why is Garbage collection that important?

I tried searching for the answer on the web and even approached my lecturers but could not find a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Your cellphone has hundreds of gigabytes of memory? You have no programs that deal with large images/videos that take hundreds of MB each?

Comment: Even with hundreds GB, A program leaking 1GB memory in a minute will crash - you know after hundreds minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a memory leak if the memory cannot be reclaimed by the system once the program has finished using a variable.

It is important, because,

1. You might say 8 bytes is a little bit of data. But what if those 8 bytes are leaked in a tight loop running millions of times per minute ? You will have exhausted memory very quickly.
2. Larger datastructures are very common. Example: A web scraper could leak representations of HTML documents, easily 100's of kB or even megabytes.
3. Though memory is cheap, 100's of gigabytes of RAM is still uncommon. You might think about disk space, and disk space is slow. When you have exhausted your RAM and the system needs to swap memory between disk and RAM to do the simplest operations, performance will degrade in the extremes.
4. Also consider mobile or embedded devices, that can have very limited memory.

True war story: I once debugged an ASP .NET system that had a tiny memory leak (I think it was about 60 bytes per request to a particular webpage). But that page was hit *a lot*, and we had to recycle application pools each hour to avoid exhausting RAM on the server. This was on a very well specced server. It also shows that leaks can even occur in garbage collected environments - we should always be aware of memory consumption.

Comment: Just to be clear.. when you say "cannot be reclaimed by the system", do u mean the memory is gone for good or just till the power remains.

Sorry but I thought the memory was memory on the HDD not the RAM
I get it now

Comment: Of course, the memory can typically be reclaimed once the program exits.

Answer (score 0):

The variable may contain only one or two words of data, but for variable whose type is some Java object, that word is really a pointer to garbage collected data, the object's state. And that object state may in turn contain pointers to other objects (or arrays of them), themselves pointing to some other object, or a previous one (circular references!) etc.

The garbage collector will only release (i.e. let the JVM reuse) memory after it is sure that no reference chain (from local or global variables) point to it.

I strongly suggest to read carefully at least Wikipedia page on [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) then if possible a textbook like [the garbage collection handbook](http://gchandbook.org/). You could also read Paul Wilson's [GC survey](ftp://ftp.cs.utexas.edu/pub/garbage/gcsurvey.ps) article from 1992.

And you should care about RAM usage; from an application point of view, accessing to a hard disk takes a very long time (accessing a kilobyte block on disk is about 10 milliseconds. accessing it on RAM is a couple of microseonds, thousand of time faster; the on-chip cache is accessible in nano-seconds.). SSD makes that a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's a big assumption to make that all variables are 2 to 8 bytes. Some may be rather large data structures, well into the megabytes in some applications.

Secondly, even a 2-byte variable leak will wreak havoc if it's in a loop running millions or billions of times, especially in a long-lived program.

Thirdly, the amount of physical memory you have may be unrelated to your process address space. For example, a 32-bit process may only be able to address 4G regardless of the fact your machine has hundreds of gigabytes.

Lastly, even if you *could* handle the leak, it's better coding style to *not* have these sorts of potential bugs. Anything else is just being sloppy :-)

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a web server which is 4Gb ram. On this web server is one website with some small memory leaks.

For this example lets say they each consume some file which requires 1Mb of memory in ram and don't clean it up after use.

Maybe the page with a leak gets called 100 times per day. All of a sudden our server is losing 100mb daily. This is bad.

Memory leaks may be small but you don't want to have to reboot your app every 30 days because it's hogging all your ram.